# Asynchronous javascript problems

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am fairly new to javascript and I am having trouble with asynchronous programming.

```
var global;

var query = {
    url: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news',
    type: 'html',
    selector: '#comp-candy-asset-munger > div > div.pigeon__column.pigeon__column--b > div:nth-child(2) > a.title-link',
    extract: 'href'
  },
  uriQuery = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query)),
  request  = 'http://example.noodlejs.com/?q=' +
             uriQuery + '&callback=?';

// Make Ajax request to Noodle server
jQuery.getJSON(request, function (data) {
  global = data[0].results;
  callback();
});

function callback() {
alert(global);
}
```

This is what I have at the moment, in callback() the variable global hold the data that I want it to. However how can I use 'global' outside of these functions while it still holds that data?

I would then like to use global in this way:

```
var query = {
        url: global,
        type: 'html',
        selector: '#comp-candy-asset-munger > div > div.pigeon__column.pigeon__column--b > div:nth-child(2) > a.title-link',
        extract: 'href'
      },
      uriQuery = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query)),
      request  = 'http://example.noodlejs.com/?q=' +
                 uriQuery + '&callback=?';

    // Make Ajax request to Noodle server
    jQuery.getJSON(request, function (data) {
      alert(data[0].results);
    });
```

Any advice or help would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use `global` outside the callback, that's basically what asynchronous means.

Comment: You can use `global` outside the callback, but only after it has gotten the value assigned. Which is signalled by the invocation of the callback.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your response, i have tried alert(global); after the callback function however the result is 'undefined'

Comment: You probably tried it (spatially) after the *declaration* of the callback. I meant (temporally) after the *invocation* of the callback - best done *inside* the callback function body. (That's why usually you don't use globals, but just pass the data as arguments to the callbacks)